# Topaz sigpad not working on latest google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, topaz-signatures

In the latest version of Google Chrome (Version 113.0.5672.64 - Official Build - 64-bit), the Topaz SigPad doesn't open the signpad popup screen on the first attempt. After that, it gives an error message indicating that **another instance is already running**. However, in the older version (Version 112.0.5615.138 - Official Build - 64-bit), it worked fine.

Comment: Topaz SigPlusExtLite Extension 3.0.28.0 - Does not work

Topaz SigPlusExtLite Extension 3.0.29.0 - Updated version that now works
To update the extention:
Reboot the Chrome browser to auto-update to Topaz SigPlusExtLite Extension 3.0.29.0

Go to chrome://extensions/

Under "Topaz SigPlusExtLite Extension" need to see if it updated to vers. 3.0.29.0 or if its still version 3.0.28.0